# List icon color in Site Contents

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-contents

I have a collection of lists that were just created in SharePoint Online. When I'm in the Site Contents overview they have different colored icons. Some are gold and some are gray.

[image: Colored List icons]

Looking at the URL image source gives two URLs:

```
Gold icon: _layouts/15/images/itgen.gif?rev=47
Gray icon: _layouts/15/images/itgen.png?rev=47
```

They only seem to differ via the the file extension, PNG or GIF.

Is there any logic to these colorings or are they just randomly assigned?

Comment: Are these list of same type? It could be that first and third lists are of different type but the second. Calendars icon is different from libraries and lists.

Answer (score 0):

These two are actually different icons in the site contents, not just one picture changing the color.

If you check the other icons in the site contents, you will find their source paths having the same format as `_layouts/15/images/<imagefile>?rev=47`. `?rev=47` represents one of the image renditions in SharePoint.

The icons are not randomly assigned. The grey icon is usually assigned to a common custom list, while the golden icon is assigned to other lists such as a list for app package.

Here’s a reference on image rendition.

[Image optimization for SharePoint Online classic publishing sites.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/image-optimization-for-sharepoint-online)